# explicite type cast is not working for overloaded constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

I've recently switched from VS6 to VS-Express 2013. Converting the old code gets me of course lots of warnings and warnings but there is one thing which I'm really struggeling with:

Why I do get an error here?

when I try to compile

```
 ParseValue op_ParseValue()
    {
        switch (m_dt)
        {
        case NUM:
            return ParseValue( (int) Value);
            break;
        case P_STRING:
            return ParseValue((const char*)Symbol_Name);
            break;
        case P_LITERAL:
            return ParseValue(Symbol_Name);
            break;
        case P_ERROR:
            return ParseValue(P_ERROR);
            break;
        }
        return ParseValue(P_ERROR);
    };
```

I get a compiler error C2668: ambiguent call to an overloaded function.

The only hints I found were to eliminate this error was to make explicite type conversions, but this I've already done. Actually I couldn't see a need for any type casts since all arguments are perfectly fitting to the constructor parameters.

This is the class definition (partly)

```
class ParseValue
    {
    public:
        ParseValue(ParseValue &pv) :_charval(""), _intval(pv._intval), _type(pv._type)
        {
            if (_type == P_LITERAL || _type == P_STRING || _type == P_REF)
            {
                _charval = pv._charval;
            }
        }
        ParseValue(DataType dt) :_charval(""), _intval(0), _type(dt)
        {
        }
        ParseValue(int num) :_charval(""), _intval(num), _type(NUM)
        {
        }

        ParseValue(TCSymbolReference &ref) :_charval(""), _intval(0), _type(P_REF)
        {
            _charval = ref.Name();
        }

        ParseValue(const char *str) :_charval(""), _intval(0), _type(P_LITERAL)
        {
            _charval = str;
        }
        ~ParseValue()
        {
        }
        ParseValue operator ==(ParseValue &other);

        ParseValue operator !=(ParseValue &other);

        ParseValue operator *(ParseValue &other);

        ParseValue operator /(ParseValue &other);
        ParseValue operator %(ParseValue &other);

        ParseValue operator +(ParseValue &other);
        ParseValue operator -(ParseValue &other);
        ParseValue operator &&(ParseValue &other);
        ParseValue operator !();
        ParseValue operator ||(ParseValue &other);
        ParseValue operator &(ParseValue &other);
        ParseValue operator |(ParseValue &other);
        ParseValue operator ^(ParseValue &other);

        ParseValue operator <(ParseValue &other);
        ParseValue operator >(ParseValue &other);
        ParseValue operator =(ParseValue &other);
        ParseValue operator =(int num)
        {
            _intval = num;
            _type = NUM;
            return *this;
        }
        operator int();
        operator char* ();
        operator void* ();
        int operator--();
        int operator++();
 }
```

Here is the compiler error (sorry it's in German)

```
1>c:\users\mkilianj\documents\testimprovement\bidl\parsetree1.h(225): error C2668: 'ParseTree::ParseValue::ParseValue': Mehrdeutiger Aufruf einer überladenen Funktion
1>          c:\users\mkilianj\documents\testimprovement\bidl\parsetree1.h(56): kann 'ParseTree::ParseValue::ParseValue(const char *)' sein
1>          c:\users\mkilianj\documents\testimprovement\bidl\parsetree1.h(51): oder "ParseTree::ParseValue::ParseValue(TCSymbolReference &)"
1>          c:\users\mkilianj\documents\testimprovement\bidl\parsetree1.h(47): oder "ParseTree::ParseValue::ParseValue(int)"
1>          c:\users\mkilianj\documents\testimprovement\bidl\parsetree1.h(44): oder "ParseTree::ParseValue::ParseValue(ParseTree::DataType)"
1>          c:\users\mkilianj\documents\testimprovement\bidl\parsetree1.h(37): oder "ParseTree::ParseValue::ParseValue(ParseTree::ParseValue &)"
```

Comment: There are many unknowns in this code. What is `TCSymbolReference` ? What is `DataType` ?  What are `Value` and `Symbol_Name` ? What is `P_ERROR` ? Why does `operator==` not return `bool` ?   Instead of starting a game of Twenty Questions, it would be better to post a self-contained code example. [This page describes how to generate such an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We need a [mcve] - one that would show the types of `Symbol_Name` and `P_ERROR` too

Comment: It might be confused as to what constructor to call because you're using pass by reference and an integer. Which are both interchangeable (on x86 architecture). Also you should use c++ style-casting (i.e. `static_cast`) instead of c style-casting.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to add const in your copy constructor:

```
ParseValue(const ParseValue &pv)
           ^^^^^ ~~~ !
```

You should always make your copy constructor take const reference argument. Otherwise, if you need no const - then use move constructor.

The reason for the error is that you are returning by value from function, so the compiler creates a temporary which is copied to any variable that you assign in function call place - using a copy constructor. The reason for compiler error is, compiler created temporary objects cannot be bound to non-const references. In your case compiler finds conversion operators, which it find suitable to do the conversion (you provide appropriate constructors), but because they are ambiguous you get error as you get.